# Accessing this.props in react ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to react and I am stuck on a certain project. The thing is that I have an `api_url` in `this.props` received from a parent component. And in this child component, I want to use `api_url` to fetch some data using JSON.

In the parent component, I have:

```
Repositories api_url={this.state.objs.repos_url}
```

and in the child component, I want something like:

```
componentDidMount() {    
    $.getJSON(this.props.api_url, function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var each_repo = json[i]
            console.log(each_repo["name"]);
        }    
    });
}
```

so what I need is the corresponding `api_url` in the url section of `$.getJSON`.

Is there a way to access `this.props` in `componentDidMount` or is there some other way to achieve the same results?

Another thing regarding this, is that I'm also using a `$.getJSON` call in the `ComponentDidMount` of the parent component.

A thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand... this.props is available in the entire class. So your code is OK.

Comment: You already can, do you mean inside `$.getJSON`?..

Comment: Your code works - http://jsbin.com/wirodemulu/edit?html,js,console,output - if you want to access `this` from within the callback function in `$.getJSON` you need to use `.bind()`.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I've bound my method in the constructor but still can't access props from anywhere except in the render() method

Answer (score 18):

In your class implement the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     //states
  };
}

componentDidMount(){
  //Get this.props
  console.log(this.props.nameOfProp);
};
```

Probably at this react version is more easy to get it.

Comment: This throw me error but if I call this.props.nameOfProp inside render it works.

Answer (score 4):

In order to access Props in the child component you need to create a constructor in the child component and then pass props as an attribute to the super() function as

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {}
}
componentDidMount(){

   $.getJSON(this.props.api_url , function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var each_repo = json[i]
        console.log(each_repo["name"]);

      }

    });

  }
```

Once you do this you can access props in your entire child component

Comment: I have already tried the same thing and it returns undefined when i logged this.props.api_url to the console

Comment: Check if this.state.objs.repos_url value in parent component

Comment: `.bind(this)` is missing after `$.getJSON`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a problem with the `this` inside your ajax call. My guess would be that you have to bind `this` in your Repositories so that the instance of `this` in your ajax call refers to Repositories and not the ajax object.

Answer (score 2):

For those who stumble on this page now, what's missing above is `.bind(this)` after `$.getJSON`. Otherwise you can't access `this` within `$.getJSON`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON(this.props.api_url, function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var each_repo = json[i]
            console.log(each_repo["name"]);
        }

    }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Not required. ComponentDidMount is a react lifecycle function and thus is already bind with the context. bind() is needed with custom functions. quoting @ShubhanKhatri

Comment: `bind` is NOT used for `componentDidMount()`, which I agree doesn't require it. It is used for the `$.getJSON()` function. The idea is to pass down `this` from `componentDidMount()` (which already has it without the use of `bind`) to `$.getJSON()` .

Answer (score 0):

My issue is similar but resolve this way

```
    let self = this
    this.props.users.map(function (u, x) {
        if (self.props.data[u.name]) {
            //Stuff
        }
    }
```

My if statement was not recognising props so used self instead

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried adding `this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);` to your constructor? This way you can reach `this` from `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Not required. ComponentDidMount is a react lifecycle function and thus is already bind with the context. bind() is needed with custom functions