# Calling props inside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to call a prop from a parent component `character=this.state.character` to be used as a condition for grabbing data from a JSON file.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'


export default class CharacterProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            profile:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = 
          Axios
            .get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/yp4sh.json")
            .then(result => {
                if (this.props.character === 'Roddick'){
                    this.setState({
                        profile: result.data[0]
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        profile: result.data[1]
                    });
                }

            })

     }

    render () {
        let whichClass = this.props.characterMenu!=='profile' ?
            'hideElement' : this.props.characterSelected ?
                'blueBackground' : 'hideElement';

        let character = this.props.character;
        let arraya = this.state.profile
        return(         
            <div className={whichClass}>
                <h1>{character} Profile</h1>
                {this.state.profile['Character']}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do this, the code seems to completely ignore `if (this.props.character === 'Roddick')`. Is there a way to use props inside this function so that I can conditionally grab data?

Comment: check this.props.character content in console.log before your if condition

Comment: Props are passed to lifecycle methods, so you don't have to use this.props. look at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @Zydnar please reread the documentation you linked more carefully, [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) receives no arguments, not all lifecycle functions receive props.

Comment: @DrewReese I didn't said it's the right lifecycle method to do it. Cheers!

Comment: @BTM so what does console log says? Or maybe move simply your code to constructor...?

Comment: @Zydnar it doesn't really say anything about this? It just skips over it and moves to the else statement.

Comment: @Zydnar just did it, it returns empty...so I guess it's not even being detected in this method?

Comment: @BTM so console.log(this.props.character) is empty (undefined) - right?

Comment: @BTM You might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543928/accessing-this-props-in-react-componentdidmount

Comment: Can you share the parent component rendering `CharacterProfile`? You should have something like `<CharacterProfile character="someCharacter"  />.

Comment: @Zydnar yeah it returned empty, so I'll go check that out

Comment: @DrewReese I did that part already, so that wasn't the issue

Comment: ok, I think I figured it out? I'm looking up the componentWillReceiveProps and getDerivedStateFromProps methods right now